# how to access the third party browser control like chrome in android?

Tags: android, google-chrome, firefox, browser, development-environment

I am trying to get list of url visited in an android app. I am able to get the list of URL visited by the android default browser, but unable to get the list of URL hit by 3rd party browsers like chrome, firefox. How can i achieve that.. Please help. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Google Chrome browser, You could get it with the following content uri:

```
content://com.android.chrome.browser/bookmarks
```

Not sure about other browsers.